# Script getting aborted with exit code 19543

Tags: linux, wget

I have a script that downloads a huge file (~4gb) as part files.
This script is called from within java thread.
This script uses *wget* utility of Linux to download the files.
Suddenly the script exits abnormally with the error message

```
19543 Aborted  /usr/bin/wget
```

Once the script fails the thread sleeps off for 1 hour and when it wakes ups it again starts downloading.
It keeps on downloading for around ~10 mins and again fails with the same error message.

The server from which it downloads, the resource management is fine and no issues with it.
Also the CPU usage in the client from which the script runs is fine.

Not understanding why this failure is happening.
Earlier the script used to download successfully from the same server with no issues.

It is downloading with 128kbps speed.

Comment: Are you able to download manually? just using wget command?

Comment: Is the file system you are saving to able to handle large files? Seems like a bit of an unlikely case, but there are still some of those out in the wild...